# Deploying App Engine Connected Android locally

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae to deploy my application locally. When I do step 6

```
Start the App Engine app (right click > Run as > Web Application).
```

I get the following error. Does anyone know how I might resolve this? I read the error, but I don't understand what to do or where to do it? Does anyone have a set of instructions I could follow?

```
objc[1130]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Missing required argument 'module[s]'
Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1
DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s] 

where 
  -noserver        Prevents the embedded web server from running
  -port            Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
  -whitelist       Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -blacklist       Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -logdir          Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
  -logLevel        The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
  -gen             Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -bindAddress     Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort  Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)
  -server          Specify a different embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
  -startupUrl      Automatically launches the specified URL
  -war             The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
  -deploy          The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
  -extra           The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
  -workDir         The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
and 
  module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the issue

- Right click the project and select **Property**
- Click **Google**
- select **Web Toolkit**
- uncheck **Use Google Web Toolkit**
- Delete the project in Run configuration.
- Run project again.

Comment: I am using Android Studio but i am not sure where is the Property option when i right click on the project.